# document.body not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a simple on click function, but IE isn't cooperating.
This works when I use it in chrome. When I call this function in IE, the function doesn't execute.
IE version: 11

```
<script language="JavaScript">
AJS.$(document).ready(function($) {

AJS.$(document.body).on("click", "#Test-button", function() {

    });

});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there errors in the console? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx Did you try to add `console.log` statements to see what is executed and what your variables are? For example: `console.log("AJS.$ is:",AJS.$)`

Comment: IE certainly has bugs, but if `document.body` really wasn't working, they would probably have noticed it. What is `AJS.$`, do you have an error in your dev-tools console?

Answer (score 0):

document.body not work in IE, remove the `body` and only use `document`

Just change your code to :

```
<script language="JavaScript">
AJS.$(document).ready(function($) {

AJS.$(document).on("click", "#Test-button", function() {

});

});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tLa4mxgp/

Answer (score 0):

Making a wild assumtion here.
`AJS.$` is your jQuery

```
AJS.$(document).find('body').on("click", "#Test-button", function() {
```